# Using for in how can one refer to next object in array

Tags: objective-c

While the "for in" loop is running, is it possible to look up the value of the next "string"?

Lets say you had an array called myArrayOfStrings that had the following values in it:

0 "Apple"
1 "Pear"
2 "Orange"
3 "Grape"

And you wanted to iterate over the array using a "for in" loop:

for (NSString* string in myArrayOfStrings)
{
    NSLog(string);
}

Is there anyway, inside of the "for in" loop to look of the value of the next string while it's running?  Lets say it was currently looking at the 1 "Pear" string.  Would there be anyway to lookup the value of the next string 2 "Orange"?

Comment: Yeah, if you want access to the actual array index it's best to use a `for(int i = ...` type loop, vs "for in".  You can keep your own index with a "for in" loop, but you lose the "connection" that the explicit loop index gives you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is not directly achievable using a foreach-style loop in objective c, there are a couple ways to accomplish the same task.

Please assume that

```
NSArray *myArrayOfStrings = @[@"Apple", @"Pear", @"Orange", @"Grape"];
```

### Standard For Loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArrayOfStrings count]; i++) {
    NSString *string = [myArrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *next_string = @"nothing";
    if (i + 1 < [myArrayOfStrings count]) { // Prevent exception on the final loop
        next_string = [myArrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:i + 1];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@ comes before %@", string, next_string);
}
```

### Object Enumeration

```
[myArrayOfStrings enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *string, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *next_string = @"nothing";
    if (idx + 1 < [myArrayOfStrings count]) { // Prevent exception on the final loop
        next_string = [myArrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:idx + 1];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@ comes before %@", string, next_string);
}];
```

Both of these options output:

```
Apple comes before Pear
Pear comes before Orange
Orange comes before Grape
Grape comes before nothing
```

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case.  I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some feature of "for in" loops that I wasn't aware of.  Thanks.

Comment: You will get an out of bounds exception when you reach the last object.  Use i < [myArrayOfStrings count] - 1 instead.

Comment: @zsnow It will when you assign to next_string, which looks for objectAtIndex:i + 1.

Comment: You may also want to look at `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]`, which loops with a block that's passed both an object *and* its index. That can save you the assignment to `string` in this example.

Comment: @BrentRoyal-Gordon Updated the post to demonstrate the method you suggested.

Comment: @zsnow Looks good, but there's actually nothing stopping you from changing `id obj` in the block's parameter list to `NSString * string`. That's what I usually do.

Comment: @BrentRoyal-Gordon Thanks for pointing that out. Post has been edited again.